# Is DB_LINQ + Non-SQL Server Database an acceptable substitute for LINQ to SQL with SQL Server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, linq

I'm trying to decide what database system to use for my next project which will be using VS.NET 2008 and will likely have a bit of LINQ code in it. No LINQ support may be a dealbreaker for any database system. Is DB_LINQ mature enough to allow other DBMS' to stand on even footing with SQL Server? Or should I just not even look into other systems if LINQ is a dealbreaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, if you are at a Microsoft shop there shouldn't be any problem using Linq to SQL for your OR/M needs.

If I needed a true OR/M solution I would experiment with Linq to Entities and use [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html) if I needed something immediately stable.  It's been around the block a few times and is pretty stable.  To my knowledge Oracle has still not shipped a true Linq to Entities implementation and until they do you'll need to get by on the various community efforts like [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/).  [Catharsis](http://www.codeplex.com/Catharsis) is a pretty good reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't used it myself - but I've *helped* somebody using it (various bits of `Expression` code - I believe some made it into the DbLinq codebase), and they were generally happy with it.

Ultimately, I suggest you need to find which are the critical features you need, and run tests (unit, integration or ad-hoc) to see if it can meet your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ != LINQ to SQL. LINQ to Entities works just fine with many non-SQL-Server DBs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using DBLinq for production code... many of Linq-To-SQL's features aren't implemented, and walking through the source code shows a low level of maturity... many of the methods are not implemented or marked as "unterminated".

...you've been warned!